# How to allow user to delete only new rows in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am using a DataGrid to show data to the user.

I am allowing the user to edit the data and add new rows. Is it possbile to use the built-in funcionality of `CanUserDeleteRows` to allow the user only to delete rows that he just added.

So usecase-description:

1) User opens datagrid
2) datagrid shows its contents
3) user adds a few rows
4) user deletes one (or all) of his added rows.
5) user is *not* able to delete rows that were in the datagrid when it initally loaded

...so only "new" rows should be able to get deleted. What approach is best here? I am a little bit out of ideas at the moment...

**UPDATE:** To satisfty your comments ;)

I am using an ObservableCollection of an custom class to fill the datagrid. So the "problem" is that I don't actually know ho to "intercept" the delete-event nor how to do it without breaking the mvvm-pattern.

Comment: What data Type are you using for Bind DataGrid? If DataTable then DataRow has Added state if new row added in DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using ObservableCollections and so on, I used a working approach, a little bit based on Aghilas Yakoub's answer.

I added a Remove-Button to the DataGrid thats visibility is bound to a `IsNew`-Property.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.BottomDetailVM.DeleteCommand}" Visibility="{Binding IsNew, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When the usere clicks the button the command is executed with the current object (that is shown in the row) as a parameter.

```
public ICommand DeleteRangfolgeCommand
{
  get
  {
     return new ActionCommand<MyOwnViewModel>(ExecuteDelete);
  }
}

private void ExecuteDelete(MyOwnViewModel viewModelToDelete)
{
    this.ItemsSourceList.Remove(viewModelToDelete);
}
```

Btw: I am using the `RelayCommand`-implementation (in my case called ActionCommand) from the [MSDN-Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030).

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices :

```
1 `Disconnected Mode`
```

You save your new rows on cache, You use `GetChanges` method in order to get added rows.

```
//GetChanges return added rows before update datasource from caching
var newRows = YourDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```

You add another Data Column, you set value of this column every time that you add new rows.

```
DataColumn columnFlag = new DataColumn("FlagDelete", typeof(bool));
```

`Delete Button` is `visible` by according with column value

‎

```
2 `Connected Mode`
```

You create in your database new column, you realize server calls in order to get your datas, and visualize your function delete according to the value of column flag